# Puppet DSL: order does not matter?

Tags: puppet

According to the Puppet documentation:

> Order does not matter in a declarative language.

If that is the case, why does this bit of code work:

```
class myserver {
  $package_to_install = 'libcapture-tiny-perl'
  package {
   $package_to_install: ensure => present;
  }
}
```

but this code does *not* work:

```
class myserver {
  package {
   $package_to_install: ensure => present;
  }
  $package_to_install = 'libcapture-tiny-perl'
}
```

If order matters, then I can see why one works and the other does not, but since order does not matter, why do they behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am one of the Puppet developers.

Because our language isn't, as our documentation claims, actually declarative.  It is actually ordered. :(

Evaluation is more or less top to bottom inside the class or declaration.  The product of that evaluation is a resource in the catalog, however, not evaluation of the catalog.

Think of the DSL as a not-entirely-declarative way to build the catalog, a graph of resources, that are entirely declarative in processing.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to some Puppet Labs document that might explain in some detail how the language is compiled and executed?

Comment: Sadly, no, there isn't.  I added some more explanation into the answer though.

Comment: So, a Puppet DSL file gets pre-compiled in the "normal" imperative manner into a structure that represents a graph of resources which is order-independent (modulo explicit dependencies). Is that correct?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes.  That summary is unlikely to steer you wrong.